# Concept of sworn sister(mooh boli behen) and mahram

Tags: mahram

In India people make women as sister (sworn sister in English or mooh boli behen in Hindi). My questions are:

1. Is it permissible to make women as sister?
2. Will these women (sworn sister) become mahram to us?

Comment: Probably not. There is a specific list of people who are mahram given, and I am sure "mooh boli" sisters are not included, unless they were breastfed by your mother.

Comment: @theZ so anyone cannot make women as sister right?

Comment: @Fawad . You cannot.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it permissible to make women as sister?

Yes, it is permissible to say any women as a sister or make them a sister.

> Will these women (sworn sister) become mahram to us?

No, they will still be Na-Muharram and indeed needs to do follow the complete ruling of hijab and they will not get anything from heirship until you in your life give anything from land or belongings.

for reference please read the tafseer of below ayath:

> وَإِذْ تَقُولُ لِلَّذِي أَنْعَمَ اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَأَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِ أَمْسِكْ عَلَيْكَ زَوْجَكَ وَاتَّقِ اللَّهَ وَتُخْفِي فِي نَفْسِكَ مَا اللَّهُ مُبْدِيهِ وَتَخْشَى النَّاسَ وَاللَّهُ أَحَقُّ أَن تَخْشَاهُ ۖ فَلَمَّا قَضَىٰ *زَيْدٌ مِّنْهَا وَطَرًا زَوَّجْنَاكَهَا لِكَيْ لَا يَكُونَ عَلَى الْمُؤْمِنِينَ حَرَجٌ فِي أَزْوَاجِ أَدْعِيَائِهِمْ إِذَا قَضَوْا مِنْهُنَّ وَطَرًا ۚ وَكَانَ أَمْرُ اللَّهِ مَفْعُولًا*

And [remember, O Muhammad], when you said to the one on whom Allah bestowed favor and you bestowed favor, "Keep your wife and fear Allah," while you concealed within yourself that which Allah is to disclose. And you feared the people, while Allah has more right that you fear Him. So when Zayd had no longer any need for her, We married her to you in order that there not be upon the believers any discomfort concerning the wives of their adopted sons when they no longer have need of them. And ever is the command of Allah accomplished.

Comment: You say that it is permissible. What's the evidence for this?